# Matrix positive definite lemma

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose I have a matrix of size $(n \times p) $, denoted $B$, and a symmetric matrix of size $(n \times n) $, denoted $A$ with $n>p$.

If I know that the matrix $BB'A$ is positive definite, can I now tell if the matrix $B'AB$ is positive definite? If so why/why not?

Comment: Should the assumption not be $BB'A$ is positive definite?

Comment: Assuming we're considering operators on a real vector space (as you specified symmetric and not Hermitian). In the case $A$ commutes with $BB'$ we have $B B' A$ is symmetric and so it is positive-definite iff all of its eigenvalues are positive. Then we can use the fact that eigenvalues are invariant under cyclic permutations ([see this SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281016/invariance-of-eigenvalues-of-a-product-of-square-matrices-under-cyclic-permutati)) to conclude that $B'AB$ has only positive eigenvalues. As $B'AB$ is symmetric and has positive eigenvalues it is PSD.

Comment: $B'BA$ is not a legitimate product of matrices.

Comment: Ah apologies yes I should have put $BB'$. Thank you @Rammus though, that answer was what I was looking for!

Comment: @JDoe2 Happy to help :)