# showing that $\sigma(\mathbf{XYX}^{−1}) = \sigma(\mathbf{Y})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, spectral-theory

I wanted to show the above ($\mathbf{X}$ is nonsingular btw), but I don't think my current proof is complete/quite right, wondering if this is ok:

Let $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{XYX}^{-1}$. Given that we can represent a matrix $\mathbf{M}$ this way, then we know $\mathbf{M}$ is diagonalizable. Notice that $\mathbf{M}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are similar matrices. So, $\mathbf{Y}$ is a diagonal matrix, that shows the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{M}$ on its diagonal.

Taking $\mathbf{Y}$ on its own, we know that one of the properties of a diagonal matrix is that its eigenvalues are on the diagonal. Since $\mathbf{Y}$ is a diagonal matrix, its eigenvalues are on its diagonal.
$$ \therefore \sigma(\mathbf{M}) = \sigma(\mathbf{XYX}^{-1}) = \sigma(\mathbf{Y}) $$

(Note: I realize $\mathbf{Y}$ is not always diagonal, how would I circumvent this?)

Comment: Also, I think you're making this too complicated: If $Yv=\lambda v$ for some nonzero $v$,  show that you can always find a nonzero $u$ such that that $XYX^{-1}u=\lambda u$.

Comment: One can also see this statement as a special case of a more general result: [Eigenvalues are invariant under cyclic permutations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281016/invariance-of-eigenvalues-of-a-product-of-square-matrices-under-cyclic-permutati), i.e., $\sigma(ABC) = \sigma(CAB) = \sigma(BCA)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess $\sigma$ represents the eigenvalues of a matrix.

If that is the case, the eigenvalue $\lambda$ should be an eigen value for both $\mathbf{XYX}^{−1}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$. That means, there are two vectors $u$ and $v$ such that

$$ Yv=\lambda v $$ and
$$ XYX^{-1} u= \lambda u 
\\ \Longrightarrow YX^{-1}u = X^{-1}(\lambda u) = \lambda X^{-1} u $$

So if we define $v$ as $X^{-1} u$ we find the associated eigenvectors for $\mathbf{XYX}^{−1}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$. So for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ (and associated eigen vector $u$) of $\mathbf{XYX}^{−1}$, $\mathbf{Y}$ has the same eigen value $\lambda$ (and associated eigen vector $X^{-1}u$)